# Move files to a network folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

Could you tell me please, how to correctly specify the path to the `network folder` from the `Linux` operating system in the code?

The network folder is accessible via `SMB`

I use the following code to move a certain type of files:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import shutil
import os
from glob import glob

for file in list(glob(os.path.join('//192.168.10.20/NEW/test1', '*.pdf'))):
    shutil.move(file, '//192.168.10.20/NEW/test2')
```

`Process finished with exit code 0`

But the files are not moved.

I tried this code on local folders - everything works fine, I think the problem is in the `wrong format` of the `path` to the `network folder` from `Linux` via `SMB`, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/33480/

Comment: shutil only works with mounted file systems, `//192.168.10.20/NEW/test2` is a location in the `/` root folder, not on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're uploading to an SMB share, you need to use [pysmb](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html) for instance.

NB. I don't have a SMB share available right now, so this is untested, but should point you in the right direction.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

conn = SMBConnection(...)
assert conn.connect(ip, port)

for file in conn.listPath("NEW", path="/test1/", pattern="*.pdf"):
    conn.rename("NEW", "/test1/" + file.filename, "/test2/" + file.filename)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm moving in this direction. did as shown here: https://gist.github.com/joselitosn/e74dbc2812c6479d3678

checked, it works, i.e. I see the directory information.

I'm trying to implement this cycle that you sent me, a lot of all kinds of errors appear, including `smb.smb_structs.operationfailure: Failed to rename 77E.pdf on new: Unable to open file/directory`

Comment: Looks like `file.filename` is only the file name and not the full path, you can do `os.path.join` of just string concatenation, see my edited answer. Hope this helps.